# How we compare xml file and json in feature file in karate framework

Tags: json, xml, compare, karate, assert

I need to compare json response with xml file.
I tied to find karate solution to find a way to compare json and xml in feature file but no feasible solution yet.

Comment: there is no "short-cut", you may need to transform one or the other. besides linked question. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+xml+json